# Is it possible to make Windows 7 log in to a password protected account automatically, only when waking the machine from hibernate?

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

Is it possible to make Windows 7 log in automatically to my password protected account, only when I wake the machine from hibernate?

I usually put my machine in hibernate when I'm gone for a short while, so it isn't at risk. But when I turn it off completely, I'm away for a bit longer and the machine might be at risk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change this with the options in the Power Control options.  Go to `Control Panel` -> `Power Options` then you should see an option on the top left of the window that says "Require a password on wakeup" and if you click that you should see this window where you can change whether you get asked for a password on wakeup.

If you are on a corporate network then this may be disabled though and there will be nothing you can do about it.

[image]